# Async IO with HttpResponse Asp.Net pre-4.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-4.0, evented-io

In particular, I'm after a similar capacity to [Response.BeginFlush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.beginflush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) being introduced in Asp.NET 4.5 which uses I/O Completion Ports.

I fear that this may not be possible because pre .NET 4 simply doesn't seem to expose enough to implement async IO with HttpResponse. [IHttpAsyncHander](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpasynchandler.aspx) is as far as things are exposed currently. It doesn't seem like there's much hope with integrating HttpListener.

I also looked into [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) with Asp.NET which seems to have the dependency on .NET 4.5.

How screwed am I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's not possible. Asp.NET simply exposes HttpResponse/HttpRequest to IHttpHandlers which really the most control it allows. You can add a filter when writing to the IO stream, but [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx)s before .NET 4.5 didn't support for asynchronous flushing. And I don't think Asp allows a custom implementation of Streams.

Edit: Asp.NET does not allow support for asynchronous writing.

Comment: There's no async write in ASP.NET. You can flush async in ASP.NET 4.5 though.

Comment: ASP.NET 4.5 also introduced asynchronous read/write without Begin(Read/Write).

Comment: That's incorrect. There's no async write in ASP.NET 4.5. Its a buffered write. However you can flush async.

Comment: Are the [Response.Output.WriteAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158638(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Response.OutputStream.WriteAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158629(v=vs.110).aspx) methods not asynchronous?

Comment: And pre .Net 4.5, [Response.Output.BeginWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginwrite.aspx) ?

Comment: That's also synchronous. WriteAsync are on Stream and HttpResponseStream (the ASP.NET impl) doesn't override them. So like I said before, it's buffered write and async flush.

Comment: I just want to clarify, by write I don't mean send. So just want to reiterate, you're saying that WriteAsync will never return without having completely finished writing? By written, I don't mean send. It's understood that after a write, you often have to flush.

Comment: There's no async write in ASP.NET.

Comment: Alright, I'm taking your word for it. But where on earth is this specified in the documentation? I wasn't able to to find the documentation for HttpResponseStream. If it doesn't exist, it probably should.

Comment: Yea, we're on the team, you should take our word for it ;). @RickAndMSFT should be able to answer that question.

Comment: Awesome, a kudos for how MVC4 Asp.NET 4.5 is coming along. Release it already! I'm quite anxious.